# android app run onPreDraw infinitely

Tags: android

Step 1. Create a new app with Navigation Drawer template.

[image: create a new app with Navigation Drawer template]

Step 2. Add a customized button and override the onMeasure method.

```
@CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehavior(MyButton.Behavior.class)
public class MyButton extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton {

private ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener mPreDrawListener;

public MyButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    if (mPreDrawListener == null) {
        mPreDrawListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                offsetTopAndBottom(50);
                return true;
            }
        };

        ViewParent p = getParent();
        if (p instanceof View) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                ((View)p).getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(mPreDrawListener);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class Behavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<MyButton> {

    @Override
    public boolean onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout parent, MyButton child, int layoutDirection) {
        final List<View> dependencies = parent.getDependencies(child);
        return super.onLayoutChild(parent, child, layoutDirection);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToLayoutParams(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp) {
        if (lp.dodgeInsetEdges == Gravity.NO_GRAVITY) {
            // If the developer hasn't set dodgeInsetEdges, lets set it to BOTTOM so that
            // we dodge any Snackbars
            lp.dodgeInsetEdges = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Step 3. Use `MyButton` in app_bar_main layout.

[image]

Step 4. Set a breakpoint in onPreDraw and then I could see it will be executed infinitely. If I comment the `offsetTopAndBottom(50)`, everything goes fine.

[image]

I also trace the source code and find app receive vsync signal again and again which cause the `onVsync` function in Choreographer.java run infinitely. Why this happens?

### Update

If I set a breakpoint as below and comment `onPreDraw`, this breakpoint finally will not be reached, otherwise, it can be reached always.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The callback `onPreDraw()` is called before each frame is drawn. Since you normally keep on drawing frames (~60fps), it is normal that it is called "infinitely".

To avoid this behavior, the usual pattern is to remove the listener as first statement in `onPreDraw()`:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
```

where `view` is the downcasted parent in your case.

You can see example code in [this video](http://graphics-geek.blogspot.ie/2013/06/devbytes-custom-activity-animations.html). The engineers are part of the Android Framework team.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my case, there is no animation, but just simple offset operation.

Comment: No worries. The technique is used in animations usually but can be used for other things as well. The important point is to remove the listener. Also, if the answer helped, consider upvoting and accepting it, so other people can refer to it in the future.